# Detecting presence of an arbitrary member

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

It is easy to write a template that will detect the presence of a specific member within a type using `void_t`:

```
#include <type_traits>

// This comes from cppreference
template<typename... Ts> struct make_void { typedef void type;};
template<typename... Ts> using void_t = typename make_void<Ts...>::type;

// primary template handles types that have no ::aMember 
template< class T, class = void_t<> >
struct has_aMember : std::false_type { };

// specialization recognizes types that do have a ::aMember
template< class T >
struct has_aMember<T, void_t<decltype( T::aMember )>> : std::true_type { };
```

Now, if I want to detect whether some other member is present, I would have to copy-paste the detector templates and just change `aMember` to `otherMember`:

```
template< class T, class = void_t<> >
struct has_otherMember : std::false_type { };

template< class T >
struct has_otherMember<T, void_t<decltype( T::otherMember )>> : std::true_type { };
```

I would like to avoid this copy-pasting and pass the member name as a parameter to a more generic version of detection template:

```
template< class T, class member, class = void_t<> >
struct has_arbitrary_member : std::false_type { };

template< class T, class member >
struct has_arbitrary_member<T, void_t<decltype( T::member )>> : std::true_type { };
```

so that I could use this `has_arbitrary_member` by passing the type and the member name to as template parameter:

```
 std::cout << has_arbitrary_member<MyType, aMember>();
 std::cout << has_arbitrary_member<MyType, otherMember>();
```

However, with the definition I drafted above, this will not compile. Is there some other way to implement such functionality?

Comment: The best you can do is something like [`std::experimental::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected).

Comment: What do you mean by "like"?  The block of code *above* is *like* those two lines.  What are your hard requirements, and how does the block of code above them fail your requirements?  I could write a better version of your code above (say, with `is_detected`), but I would have no way if that is what you want.

Comment: @Yakk I added a sentence to the end of the question to specify my intent more clearly. Of course void_t is not a requirement, although I see that `is_detected` is implemented using `void_t` itself. Does this help?

Comment: @Rostislav: It's still a bit unclear IMHO. You get SFINAE by using T::myMember, so template selection should work regardless. Can you give an example of what you'd like your code to look like (that doesn't need detectors for each data member)?

Comment: @AndyG Is this better?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't possible in general because you **cannot suppress name lookup** on `aMember` unless you modify the token stream using a macro. It follows that you can never get away with using a name that is not in scope, unless you are currently *inside* SFINAE, which will suppress the error.

This means you really do have to write a separate template for each name.

This is one of those cases where using macros is not a bad idea, although that depends on whether you really do need to check for members of a specific name, or whether there are better ways to accomplish your objective.

Comment: This is rather a theoretical curiosity-induced question. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Rostislav For what its worth its not too hard to do with stringification

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot pass a member name as a template parameter without mentioning what class/struct the member name comes from.

And if that class/struct doesn't have that member name, then the code has an error.

Now, `void_t< decltype( &MyType::some_member ) >` is either `void` or a substitution failure depending on if `some_member` exists.  Often that solves a SFINAE problem where you don't need a compile time bool.

If you want code to run if some type *does not* have a member, can do this with careful choice of overload order, or template specializations, etc.

It is not as powerful as `has_arbitrary_member<MyType, some_member>`.

```
template<class T>
using some_member_type = decltype( std::declval<T>().some_member );
```

is a simple trait that, with [std::experimental::is_detected](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) you can do:

```
is_detected_v< some_member_type, T >
```

or

```
template<class T>
constexpr bool has_some_member_v = is_detected_v< some_member_type, T >;
```

which behaves like `has_arbitrary_member<MyType, some_member>`.  I find that is best in practice.

Comment: Thanks! I was just hoping that I missed something and there's a way around copy-paste or macros in this case. But at least I learned something new - the is_detected stuff. Just a small question - is it correct that Library Fundamentals v2 is a TS aimed at c++17?